$\max{\text{Tr}|AXA^{T}+BXB^{T}|}$ where $X^2=I$
Suppose $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are given matrices. What is the value for this optimization problem and can this be expressed in terms of $A$ and $B$?
\begin{align*}
    &\max{\text{Tr}|AXA^{T}+BXB^{T}|}\\
    \text{s.t  }& X=X^{T},X^2=I
\end{align*}
The problem is easy for $\max{\text{Tr}|AXA^{T}|}$, because $\text{Tr}|AXA^{T}|\leq ||A||_2||X||_2||A^T||_2\leq ||A||^2$ (the dimension normalizer is omit,$||·||_2$ is the Spectral 2-norm). Using this method we can get an upper bound: $||AA^T||_2+||BB^{T}||_2$ but the equality may not hold.
Update: For a Hermitian or real symmetric matrix $A$, $Tr|A|=\sum_i|\lambda_i| $, $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$

What is $\text{Tr}|\cdot|$ here? Trace norm?

@HackR Yes, I updated.

The eigenvalues of $X$ are all equal to $\pm 1$. I suspect that we can show that having $-1$ as an eigenvalue cannot be optimal, so that all eigenvalues of $X$ must be $1$, which is to say that we must have $X = I$.

Note that $X$ is an orthogonal matrix. Let $U$ be the unitary factor in the polar decomposition $AXA^T+BXB^T=PU$. Then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}|AXA^T+BXB^T|
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((AXA^T+BXB^T)U^T\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}AX&BX\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A^TU^T\\ B^TU^T\end{bmatrix}
\right)\\
&\le\left\|\begin{bmatrix}AX&BX\end{bmatrix}\right\|_F
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A^TU\\ B^TU\end{bmatrix}\right\|_F
\quad\text{(Cauchy-Schwarz)}\\
&=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A&B\end{bmatrix}\right\|_F^2
\quad\text{(as $X$ and $U$ are orthogonal)}\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(AA^T+BB^T)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}|AA^T+BB^T|.
\end{align*}
Hence the maximum of $\operatorname{tr}|AXA^T+BXB^T|$ is attained at $X=I$ and the maximum value is $\operatorname{tr}|AA^T+BB^T|=\operatorname{tr}(AA^T+BB^T)=\|A\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2$.
Remark. The stronger inequality $|AXA^T+BXB^T|\preceq AA^T+BB^T$ (without taking traces on both sides) is not always true. Consider $B=0$,
\begin{align*}
&A=\pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&2},\ X=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1},\ AA^T=\pmatrix{5&-4\\ -4&5},\ AXA^T=\pmatrix{3\\ &-3},\\
&AA^T-|AXA^T|=AA^T-3I=\pmatrix{2&-4\\ -4&2}\text{ is not PSD.}
\end{align*}

Oh my god this teaches me so much

I think you can shorten this to $\big \Vert AXA^T +BXB^T\big \Vert_{S_1}\leq \big \Vert AXA^T\big \Vert_{S_1} +\big \Vert BXB^T\big \Vert_{S_1}\leq \text{trace}\big(AA^T +BB^T\big)$ where the right inequality follows from von Neumann Trace applied to $(AX)A^T$ and $(BX)B^T$ and $S_1$ denotes the Schatten 1 norm

@user8675309 Yes, I realised that too after posting my answer, but I didn’t want to make too many edits.

I actually think von Neumann trace and Weyl's Inequalities are too much machinery for OP so I'm going to give a simplified proof

@user8675309 Ahh, triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz will do. But I think Grossman’s answer is good because it gives a more refined result, namely, $\big|\lambda_i(|AXA^T|)\big|\le\lambda_i(AA^T)$.

The trace norm also known as the Schatten 1 norm is a norm so it obeys the triangle inequality which yields the result
$\big \Vert AXA^T +BXB^T\big \Vert_{S_1}\leq \big \Vert AXA^T\big \Vert_{S_1} +\big \Vert BXB^T\big \Vert_{S_1}\leq \text{trace}\big(AA^T +BB^T\big)$
Note the right hand inequality holds since e.g.
$\big \Vert AXA^T\big \Vert_{S_1} \leq \big \Vert A^TAX\big \Vert_{S_1}=\big \Vert A^TA\big \Vert_{S_1}=\text{trace}\big(AA^T \big) $
where $AXA^T$ and $A^TAX$ have the same eigenvalues but the former is normal so
$\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^{(AXA^T)} =\sum_{k=1}^n \big\vert\lambda_k^{(AXA^T)}\big\vert= \sum_{k=1}^n \big\vert\lambda_k^{(A^TAX)}\big\vert\leq  \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^{(A^TAX)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^{(A^TA)}$
where the right hand side holds since multiplication by orthogonal matrices does not change singular values.  The upper bound is met with equality iff $A^TA X$ is normal (see 'deferred proof' in Kronecker Product of Normal Matrices) which occurs iff $X$ commutes with $A^TA$.

Hmm, isn’t Cauchy-Schwarz easier? Let $AXA^T=PU$ be a polar decomposition. Then $$|AXA^T|_{S_1}=\operatorname{tr}(AXA^TU^T)\le|XA^T|_F|A^TU^T|_F=|A|F^2=|AA^T|{S_1}.$$

@user1551 It depends.  The Schatten 1 norm triangle inequality is met with equality iff $AXA^T$ and $BXB^T$ have a common choice of orthogonal matrix $U$ for Polar Decomposition. (I couldn't find this condition on the site so I gave a proof earlier this year here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87982/old-amm-problem/4928314#4928314 ; that uses the same inequality I did above).  It still seems like there is something to be done with that info.  If not, then yes... I used to try to prove as many things as possible on this site with CS-Inequality but perhaps I'm out of the habit.

@user8675309 You were right; my proof was flawed.
